# Put request to upload zip file to Azureblob. Response as created but No file in blob

Tags: rest, azure-blob-storage, put, snaplogic

I’m trying to upload zip using put request to azure url.
as a result of PUT request i’m getting 201 (created) as result of request.
[Snaplogic Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f5paI.png)

Here is the details i’m using to upload a file
Blob Url: https://symphnytstcjgrk509.blob.core.windows.net/dmf/GHD%20Forecast%20Interface%20BY.xml?sv=2014-02-14&sr=b&sig=XXXst=2022-11-30T12%3A59%3A44Z&se=2022-11-30T13%3A34%3A44Z&sp=rw
Content-Type : application/zip
Upload transfer request type: Calculate content length
x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob

The same is getting successfully executed from Post man and the file is uploaded

Do you know what's happening here?

Answer (score 0):

I have uploaded the zipfile using code and able to fetch the file using postman and also using urls.

1. *Create a storage in Azure*
   [image]
2. *Create a container*
   [image]
   *Code Snippet:*

```
string connection_String = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("AzureWebStorage");
            string container_Name = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ContainerName");
            var file = req.Form.Files["File"];
            var filecontent = file.OpenReadStream();
            var blobClient = new BlobContainerClient(connection_String, container_Name);
            var blob = blobClient.GetBlobClient(file.FileName);
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(filecontent.ToString());
            using (Stream myblob = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
            {
                await blob.UploadAsync(myblob);
            }
            return new OkObjectResult("file uploaded successfylly");
```

*Zip File Uploaded*

[image]

And also, able to upload and download using URLs.